# MySql no funciona al instalar xampp

Tags: mysql, linux, phpmyadmin, xampp

He instalado xampp para linux, pero no funciona. Al acceder a `penguin.linux.test/phpmyadmin` (en el navegador) me salen estos errores.

1. MYSQL dice:
   No se puede conectar: parametros incorrectos.
2. mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/2002): No such file or directory
3. La conexió del usuario de control ha fallado, tal como esta definido ahora en la configuración.
4. mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/2002): No such file or directory
5. phpMyAdmin ha intentado conectar con el servidor MySQL, pero el servidor ha refusado la conexión. Comprovad el amfitrión, el nombre de usuario i la contraseña en vuestro archivo config.inc.php i asseguraos que corresponde con la información facilitada por el administrador del servidor MySQL

Que debo hacer?

PD: `penguin.linux.test` es mi `http://localhost`

Comment: Es rarísimo que se use XAMPP en Linux. ¿Es oficial el software? Además, ¿está corriendo el servicio de MySQL?

Comment: @padaleiana si, si que es web oficial

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al final basta con cambiar el puerto MySQL de `3306` a `3307` en el archivo `/opt/lampp/etc/my.cnf`. Es decir de

```
port: 3306
```

a

```
port: 3307
```

en dos lineas diferentes (las primeras dos occurrencias que haya)

Esto deberia funcionar y no dar error

Answer (score 0):

Si estas en ubuntu sigue estos pasos:

```
$ cd /opt/lampp/etc
$ sudo nano my.cnf
```

busca en las primeras lineas el puerto 3306 y cambialo a 3307.
Si usaste nano como editor de texto, haz ctrl+o para guardar y ctrl+x para salir.

ahora reinicia xampp y ya deberia funcionar

Comment: Que aporta esto a la respuesta aceptada, cuando dice basicamente lo mismo?